# AngularJS changes to the $scope properties aren't reflected in the view without calling $scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/2gD0AB. This plunk doesn't seem to work correctly because `$scope.$on("$viewContentLoaded")` won't fire, but on my machine it works just fine and I hope you get the idea.

What I'm trying to do there is simply move field objects from `$scope.fields` to `$scope.groupFields = [], $scope.listFields = [], $scope.dataFields = []` when dragging them to the appropriate droppable areas. I've manager to do this using jQuery UI and jQuery UI touch punch (just to be mobile safe).

If you drag an element from the fields box to the one of the empty boxes you'll notice nothing happens on the screen besides the field elements hanging around where you left them. But if do a `console.log($scope.fields)` in the `drop` event listener you'll notice that all of the field objects are correctly set inside each of the field boxes.

If you click the Add element button then you'll simply trigger `console.log($scope.groupFields);` and suddenly all the elements appear correctly in their corresponding boxes like intended in the first place.

After pulling my brains out and after searching the internet for some time I found out that `$scope.$apply()`, called in the `drop` event after the `moveField` function, actually fixes my issue.

And I don't understand why. Shouldn't there be a `digest` already running and updating the view based on what I'm doing in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the code that handles these jQuery `drop` events is inside the controller, it doesn't mean it will run under the angularjs scope/word. For those changes to make effect, you will need to force the angularjs app to do a dirty checking on its models. That can be accomplished by calling `$apply()` or `$digest()` methods. You should always call one of these methods after handling an jQuery event that changes `$scope` properties or after a `timeout` (or `interval`).